# Switch tabs by jquery hover, add remove class{display:none}

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, display

I have a 3 components that I wish to toggle display.

The toggle mechanic I wish to have is:

1. Only one #wrap is in display at any point of time. Default can be any #wrap.
2. Once mouse detected hovering in category1, wrap1 will display and wrap2 and wrap3 will be hidden. Same for category2, category3.
3. Mouse can then leave category1 but wrap1 will still be in display. Same for category2, category3.
4. Once mouse detected hovering in another category, the corresponding wrap will take over and be the new "active" display.
5. Basically the active display is "activated" by a hover over the category div.
6. I have provided a jsfiddle, code might be too long to paste here.

Right now the javascript code looks fine but it does not work at all. Appreciate any help thanks!

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

      $("#catbox1").mouseenter( function () {
        $("#wrap1").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap2").addClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap3").addClass('hidden');
      });

      $("#catbox2").mouseenter( function () {
        $("#wrap1").addClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap2").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap3").addClass('hidden');
      });

      $("#catbox3").mouseenter( function () {
        $("#wrap1").addClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap2").addClass('hidden');
        $("#wrap3").removeClass('hidden');
      });

  }(jQuery)); // End of use strict
```

Fiddle Update:
Removed unneccessary elements and made more notations.

Basically it seems that the mouseenter function is not working, I dont feel classes are being added or removed from the wraps because their display is always ON.

https://jsfiddle.net/0rsph8s8/20/

Comment: I think the problem is with my css, I have yet to put up css refering to '#wrap1 .hidden'.

Comment: You want wrap to display by default ?

Comment: @Loading.. i want the first wrap to display by default. Thanks for asking!

Comment: You know your CSS 
.boxInner:hover .titleBox {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

is doing everything till now ? Your jquery don't play a single role till now in your code.

Comment: Doing everything you mean it is working? Yea it is. Ive updated the fiddle. for you to test it easier.

Comment: So what's the problem now ?

Comment: @Loading.. I see! My jquery isnt needed for the hover over titleBox. I want my jquery to actually toggle the displays of the wraps, not sure why it isnt working. I have referred to the ID elements correctly hopefully, not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Please note there is a difference between class wrap and ID wrap1, wrap2, wrap3

Comment: when i hover cat1 you want to see wrap1, and so on, right ?

Comment: Yup, and so on. The catch is after u hover on cat1, and remove ur mouse from cat1, I still want to see wrap1 UNTIL you move in to another cat, then u display that particular wrap.

Comment: See I've posted my code, removed unnecessary css / html to make sure that it gives the output as your want. You can make necessary changes as per you need in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I've filtered your code and show a way to show / hide as per corresponding clicked element.

You just need to add / remove the class.

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  
  $("#catbox1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").removeClass('hidden');    
    $("#wrap2").addClass('hidden');
    $("#wrap3").addClass('hidden');
  });

  $("#catbox2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").addClass('hidden');
    $("#wrap2").removeClass('hidden');
    $("#wrap3").addClass('hidden');
  });

  $("#catbox3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").addClass('hidden');
    $("#wrap2").addClass('hidden');
    $("#wrap3").removeClass('hidden');
  });

}(jQuery)); // End of use strict
```

```css
.hidden
{
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="catbox" id="catbox1">
      <div class="catboxInner">
        <div class="catboxInnerText">Winding garden path</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="catbox" id="catbox2">
      <div class="catboxInner">
        <div class="catboxInnerText">Winding garden path</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="catbox" id="catbox3">
      <div class="catboxInner">
        <div class="catboxInnerText">Winding garden path</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap" id="wrap1">
    wrap1
  </div>  
  <!--end of wrap-->

  <div class="wrap hidden" id="wrap2">
    wrap2
  </div>
  <!--end of wrap-->

  <div class="wrap hidden" id="wrap3">
    wrap3
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: @iWillGetBetter No problem, Dear glad to see that it's finally worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

`.show()` Displays the matched elements.

`.hide()` Hides the matched elements.

Try This:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  $("#catbox1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").show();
    $("#wrap2").hide();
    $("#wrap3").hide();
  });

  $("#catbox2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").hide();
    $("#wrap2").show();
    $("#wrap3").hide();
  });

  $("#catbox3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#wrap1").hide();
    $("#wrap2").hide();
    $("#wrap3").show();
  });

}(jQuery)); // End of use strict
```

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/0rsph8s8/10/

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan Thanks this worked! Only thing is needed to write additional css lines to make sure not all 3 wraps are shown when refreshed.  See Loading answer below. Thank you!